# remove rows with non english item in json files using python

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I have a json file (data.json) that contain rows of data in json format. I want to loop through each row and remove rows of data that contains thai language under the name portion using python. May I know how to do this? Thanks

input:

```
{"name":"John", "age":30, "car":audi}
{"name":"สมศักดิ์", "age":25, "car":mercedes}
{"name":"อาทิตย์", "age":49, "car":bently}
{"name":"Mark", "age":20, "car":null}
...
```

output:

```
{"name":"John", "age":30, "car":audi}
{"name":"Mark", "age":20, "car":null}
...
```

Comment: what is your code so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would harness [`unicodedata`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html) built-in module for this as follows, let say that you have `file.txt` with content as follows

```
{"name":"John","age":30,"car":"audi"}
{"name":"สมศักดิ์","age":25,"car":"mercedes"}
{"name":"อาทิตย์","age":49,"car":"bently"}
{"name":"Mark","age":20,"car":null}
```

then

```
import json
import unicodedata
with open("file.txt",encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for line in f:
        name = json.loads(line)["name"]
        if "THAI" not in unicodedata.name(name[0]):
            print(line, end="")
```

output

```
{"name":"John","age":30,"car":"audi"}
{"name":"Mark","age":20,"car":null}
```

Disclaimer: I assume every line is legal JSON which does hold some `name`. Explanation: I iterate over lines, for line I parse it using `json.loads` and get `name` then using `unicodedata` I get Unicode name of first character and if it does not have `THAI` in its name do print said line. As lines does already have their newlines I used `end=""` (empty string) in `print`.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used this with Thai strings myself, but you could try the function [isalpha()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_isalpha.asp). This should return true if all the characters are are in the (a-z) alphabet.

```
if row["name"].isalpha():
    # english
else:
    # thai
```

Note: Using it this way will filter everything non-english, it's not specific to Thai. Not sure if that's a problem for you.